# Power Transformer question to power a motor load

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, current, transformer

So I bought a toroidal power transformer that can output 117Vac, 12.8A and has a power rating of 1.5kVA in order to power a motor that requires 115Vac, 13A. I wanted to see if this would be viable to power the motor or if I should try another solution? Below is attached the motor requirements. Hope to get some feedback.

[image]

Comment: How are you going to avoid saturation from say 500% to 800% start current?

Comment: What Sunny is saying is motors usually require 5 to 8 times full-load current to start.  And the maximum you can have just full-load current.

Comment: I guess I didn't take this into account, I have the original power supply for the motor which runs from a type 2 U.S. plug and I have to make a custom power supply to power the motor and also power a rechargeable battery and two MCU's. Do you have any recommendations to provide that much current to start the motor?

Comment: What load is on the motor? A lightly loaded motor may start without problems on your transformer using a simple softstart.  Why do you need the transformer at all? The motor is rated for 117V, why does it need to be isolated from the mains? The voltage difference 115 - 117V can easily be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use that transformer to run that motor. You need not worry about the inrush current starting the motor as this will just be a momentary saturation of the core of the transformer that dissipates in a few cycles, not long enough for eddy currents or hysteresis losses to create enough heat to even notice. The energy will be an unconstrained magnetic field - leakage flux.

Power transformers are designed to operate a range of input voltages as line voltages vary throughout the day. A  Tx (transformer) or motor with a label of 115V will operate fine from 110V to 120V and actually from 100V to 130V with little or no detrimental effects; a slight rise in operating temp. Transformers HAVE to be over-designed due to imperfect construction; variations in core metallurgy and copper inconsistencies.

@Jack:
Load on the motor will not matter unless it is at its max brake HP rating (stalled) in which case it can't be started. and many motors are isolated (especially in manufacturing) due to static charges that can build in equipment; starting or stopping of other equipment on the same circuit etc.

@stainless steel rat:
transformers can produce much more than full load current - short circuit current for example, which due to the capacitive impedance of a motor; capacitors for run/start capacitive effect winding to winding; capacitive effect turn to turn of the windings so that on initial start up it looks like big plates to store energy until the inductance of the windings begin to build a magnetic field.

Senior Transformer Design Engineer,
Electric and Electronic Transformers